# libcurl - curl_slist_append()

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I have problem with curl_slist_append.
code :

```
int my1 = rand() % 100;
int my2 = system ("dir");
int my3= time(NULL);

headers = curl_slist_append(headers,my1);
headers = curl_slist_append(headers,my2);
headers = curl_slist_append(headers,my3);

warning: passing argument 2 of ‘curl_slist_append’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
```

I solved the problem. Wireshark tested everything works OK.

```
int my1 = time(NULL);
char str[15];
sprintf(str, "%d", my1);
headers = curl_slist_append(headers,str);
```

Comment: Well, as the compiler is telling you, you can't use that function like that. The doc clearly says that function it appends strings to string lists, not integers or anything else

Comment: The warning seems clear enough: you passed an int to a function expecting a string. Looks like you're coming from a dynamic language. C will not automagically convert values to other types for you.